# How to implement XC-20 standard

Tags: xcm, astar, moonbeam, erc20

I need help understanding XC-20 implementation and how its components interact. Suppose I run a parachain (`ParaA`) that aims to supports XC-20. I need to include Frontier so `ParaA` is fully EVM compatible. As far as I understood, I can transfer tokens from another parachain (`ParaB`) to `ParaA` by creating a foreign asset in `ParaA` and using [`limited_reserve_transfer_assets`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L1172) from `pallet-xcm` in `ParaB` side. Therefore, could we state that **the key components to implement XC-20 standard** in `ParaA` are:

- XCM configuration for executing XCM operations
- [`pallet-assets`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1e878780a54791c627bf6eae210b77e1bd5f098f/substrate/frame/assets/README.md#L1) that allows create foreign assets
- Frontier for EVM compatibility

Also, what is the role of the [`x-tokens`](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/tree/master/xtokens) pallet in XC-20? Does it offer any benefits over using `pallet-xcm` alone?